# Php read from file with a space

Tags: php, parsing

I have a txt file formatted like this:

```
string1 value
string2 value
string3 value
```

I have to parse the "value" that change from an external script, but the stringX are static.
How can I get the value by each line?

Comment: Have you tried something on your own?

Comment: do some research on google before asking

Comment: I have a problem with the space, I dunno how can I deal with it.

Comment: You can explode on line breaks (`\n`) and if you are sure tat values won't have white spaces take everything after white space, but I'd suggest to change white-space with equal sign and you'll be able to handle this txt file as ini files.

Answer (score 2):

That should work for you.

```
$lines = file($filename);
$values = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^string(\d+) ([A-Za-z]+)$/', $line, $matches)) {
        $values[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
    } 
}

print_r($values);
```

Comment: Its working but not a really good solution when the file is very large. Then you but all in an array and memory. Perhaps its better to read the every line of the file and work with it.

Comment: That's right. However he may do some research himself - what he appearantly did not so far.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you. It reads one line at a time, and even if Text.txt contains 1000 lines, if you do a `file_put_contents` each time, like `file_put-contents("result.txt", $line[1])`, file will be updated every time it reads **a line** (or any action you want will be executed), not **after** reading all the 1000 lines. And at any given time, only one line is in memory.

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("Text.txt", "r") or die("Couldn't open File");
while (!feof($fp)) { //Continue loading strings till the end of file
    $line = fgets($fp, 1024); // Load one complete line
    $line = explode(" ", $line);

    // $line[0] equals to "stringX"
    // $line[1] equals to "value"

    // do something with $line[0] and/or $line[1]
    // anything you do here will be executed immediately
    // and will not wait for the Text.txt to end.

} //while loop ENDS

?>
```